# Abort connection in case of Unauthorized JWT sent in http request to Web API .net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, file-upload, asp.net-core, jwt

I am writing a .net Core 2.0 Web API controller that performs file upload using a multipart type http request and is based in the streaming technique described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads#uploading-large-files-with-streaming).

At this point I have to say that I if you want you can skip the next two paragraphs that describe the reason that led me to the need for a solution to the problem that is described after the two paragraphs.

I initially thought of authenticating the user by sending authentication data in the first section of the multipart request and validating the user as soon as the user data are read, by contacting the database and performing the proper request. However, I thought that since this is a streaming request, any delay in authenticating the user using the database, would delay reading the stream with the file. This would cause the TCP receive buffer to fill with data (possibly also increase its size) and would defeat the purpose of streaming the file (instead of buffering), since memory consumption for this connection would increase.

In order to get rid of this issue I thought of using a 2 step authentication using [JWTs](https://jwt.io/introduction/). The Web API user will first perform a request and ask for a JWT. Then it would use this JWT in the upload request. As I understand it, JWT authentication should be much faster than a database request since it is performed by validating the JWT using the key stored in the server, so the previous issue should not exist.

I implemented the JWT authentication for the upload request following this very good description from [Auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-asp-dot-net-core-2-applications-with-jwts/) and it worked just fine. More specifically the controller has an `[Authorize]` attribute that forces Web API to to authenticate the user by validating the JWT before the controller is executed.

The problem I am facing is that with the above proposed solution when an unauthorized user tries to upload a file the Controller action is never called. The Authentication engine returns an Unathorized (401) response to the user and lets the user continue sending file data. The last part is my problem. I would like unauthorized users, which are probably attackers, to receive the 401 response and then have their connection terminated.

So, what I want is to keep the authentication/authorization part as it already works and also terminate the user connection after sending the 401 response. I know (and have also tested it) that from inside a controller action method an http connection can be terminated by calling

```
HttpContext.Abort();
```

I suspect that by using a filter, I could do what I want but I am not very familiar with filters so that is why I am asking.

Comment: You could also remove the authorize attribute and do is explicitly in the action. Call HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync to get the user. If success then continue, else send a 401 with a connection: close and content-length: 0. Call flush on the response body to make it send, and then call Abort.

Comment: Thank you. I followed your suggestion and it works! I actually did `if (!(await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync()).Succeeded)` and inside the if block I formed the response and aborted the connection as @Ashkan did in the filter.

Comment: @Tratcher, I think you should write down your answer too, it is very simple and it works. I will upvote it.

Comment: Go ahead and post your working code as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve that by using an `IAuthorizationFilter`.
Inside it, we gonna set an special `ActionResult` called `AbortUnauthorizedConnectionResult` and in that we set the Status Code to `401` and Content-Length to `0` and by calling `Response.Body.Flush()` we make sure it's sent to client before we call `Abort()`.

Here we have an AuthorizationFilter called `AbortUnauthorizedConnections`:

```
class AbortUnauthorizedConnections : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.User?.Identity == null || !context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // by setting this we make sure the pipe-line will get short-circuited.
            context.Result = new AbortUnauthorizedConnectionResult();
        }
    }
}
```

And because we have inherited from `Attribute` we can use it on the upload action like this:

```
[Authorize]
[AbortUnauthorizedConnections]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile()
{
    // we do whatever we want.
}
```

Here is the code for `AbortUnauthorizedConnectionResult`:

```
class AbortUnauthorizedConnectionResult : StatusCodeResult
{
    public AbortUnauthorizedConnectionResult() : base(401)
    {
    }

    public override async Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
        await base.ExecuteResultAsync(context);
        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", "0");
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body.Flush();
        context.HttpContext.Abort();
    }
}
```

Now if an unauthorized user try to access this controller will get 401 and it's connection gets aborted.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Your solution does abort the connection in case of unauthorized access but the controller action method ('UploadFile()' in your example) is still invoked after that. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: @retset, np. edited the answer to prevent some exceptions and the problem you said.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tested it and it works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I actually implemented due to its simplicity, following @Tratcher's advice:

First, I deleted the `[Authorize]` attribute from my Controller Action method. Then I wrote the beginning of my Controller Action method as follows:

```
    public async Task<string> UploadFile()
    {
        if (!(await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync()).Succeeded)
        {
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401; //Unauthorized
            HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", "0");
            HttpContext.Response.Body.Flush();
            HttpContext.Abort();
            return null;
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Response.ContentLength.